# What's the proper way to save state in a zsh plugin?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm writing a simple plugin that needs to remember the last directory the user has visited (across all sessions). I'm thinking I'll use a file to store the path to the directory, but I'd hate to dump this `.stupid_plugin_file_conf_file` in the user's home directory. A better alternative would be to store it in the script's parent directory. 
What's common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin and any files it uses should go in a subdirectory under `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins`.